# How to add SELECT ALL function in Search Container?

Tags: search, liferay, containers

I want to have a **SELECT ALL** function in my **Search Container** like this:

[image]

This is my code of Search container :

```
<liferay-ui:search-container delta="5">
<%-- <c:choose>
<c:when test="">
</c:when>
<c:otherwise>
</c:otherwise>
</c:choose> --%>
<liferay-ui:search-container-results
results="<%= RegUserAccountLocalServiceUtil.getRegUserAccounts(searchContainer.getStart(), searchContainer.getEnd()) %>"
total="<%= RegUserAccountLocalServiceUtil.getRegUserAccountsCount() %>"
/>

<liferay-ui:search-container-row
className="com.pmti.bir.triu.model.RegUserAccount"
keyProperty="acctId"
modelVar="aRegUserAccount" >

 <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text>
<input name="rowChecker" type="checkbox" value="<%=aRegUserAccount.getAcctId()%>" />
</liferay-ui:search-container-column-text> 

<liferay-ui:search-container-column-text 
property="acctStatusFlag" name="STATUS" 
orderable="<%=true %>"/>

<liferay-ui:search-container-column-text property="acctFirstName" 
name="FULL NAME"  orderable="<%= true %>"/>

<liferay-ui:search-container-column-text property="acctEmailAdd"
name="USERNAME" orderable="<%= true %>"/>

<liferay-ui:search-container-column-text property="acctBusinessName" name="POSITION"  orderable="<%= true %>"
orderableProperty="acctLevelStatus"/>

<liferay-ui:search-container-column-text property="createdBy"
name="DIVISION" orderable="<%=true %>"/>

<liferay-ui:search-container-column-text property="acctUsername" name="USER TYPE"  orderable="<%= true %>"
orderableProperty="acctUsername"/>

<liferay-ui:search-container-column-jsp
align="right"
path="/html/viewuseraccount/view_user_actions.jsp"
/>
</liferay-ui:search-container-row>

<liferay-ui:search-iterator />
</liferay-ui:search-container>
```

And this is what it looks like:

[image]

How will I achieve to have a Select all inside my Search container? I don't know how. Please help me. Thank you very much in advance! Good day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify [rowChecker](http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/javadocs/com/liferay/portal/kernel/dao/search/RowChecker.html) attribute to search-container tag.

e.g. `rowChecker=<%=new RowChecker(renderResponse)%>`

And you can get all-selected values by example code below.

```
Liferay.Util.listCheckedExcept(document.<portlet:namespace />fm, "<portlet:namespace />allRowIds");
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Pankajkumar Kathiriya it's now working like magic! :) ^_^ Thank you.